# ¿Cómo agregar elementos a un objeto y ese objeto a un array en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, array

Realizo una consulta a MongoDB y obtengo un array "graphData" de objetos de la siguiente forma:

```
[
  {
    _id: 5e136f9dc88b620017806fe7,
    c_amount: 225,
    c_cDate: 2020-01-06T17:34:21.572Z
  },
  {
    _id: 5e137f81c60a0d00178deb50,
    c_amount: 180,
    c_cDate: 2020-01-06T18:42:09.314Z
  },
  {
    _id: 5e138230c60a0d00178deb53,
    c_amount: 180,
    c_cDate: 2020-01-06T18:53:36.661Z
  },
  {
    _id: 5e13835dc60a0d00178deb56,
    c_amount: 180,
    c_cDate: 2020-01-06T18:58:37.709Z
  },
  {
    _id: 5e138470c60a0d00178deb59,
    c_amount: 50,
    c_cDate: 2020-02-07T19:03:12.496Z
  }
]
```

Quiero trabajar con estos elementos y crear un Array nuevo que contenga todos los elementos ya "Trabajados" por lo que realice el siguiente código:

```
const data2Graph = [], dataObj2Graph = {};

    graphData.forEach( element => {
        const date2Graph = moment( element.c_cDate).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
        dataObj2Graph.date = date2Graph;
        console.log(dataObj2Graph.date); //06-01-2020
        const amount2Graph = element.c_amount;
        dataObj2Graph.amount = amount2Graph;
        console.log(dataObj2Graph.amount); //225
        data2Graph.push(dataObj2Graph);
        console.log(dataObj2Graph); //{ date: '06-01-2020', amount: 225 }
    } );
    console.log(data2Graph);
```

*Anoté en la misma línea del Console.log el resultado que me da, el único que anotaré a continuación es el último resultado del último console.log

```
[
  { date: '07-02-2020', amount: 50 },
  { date: '07-02-2020', amount: 50 },
  { date: '07-02-2020', amount: 50 },
  { date: '07-02-2020', amount: 50 },
  { date: '07-02-2020', amount: 50 }
]
```

El problema es que me da de resultado un array, pero que contiene el último elemento repetido la cantidad de elementos totales cuando el resultado que espero es algo así:

```
[
  { date: '06-01-2020', amount: 225 },
  { date: '06-01-2020', amount: 180 },
  { date: '06-01-2020', amount: 180 },
  { date: '06-01-2020', amount: 180 },
  { date: '07-02-2020', amount: 50 }
]
```

¿Me podrían ayudar a obtener el resultado deseado?

Comment: Creo que sería más fácil usar el método `map` que `forEach`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El uso de `const` no te permite sustituir valores, en su lugar utiliza `let`, revisa el siguiente código optimizado

```
let data2Graph = [];
graphData.forEach( element => {
    let dataObj2Graph = {
        date: moment( element.c_cDate).format('DD-MM-YYYY'),
        amount: element.c_amount
    };
    data2Graph.push(dataObj2Graph);
});
console.log(data2Graph);
```

Comment: Realmente el problema es que se declaró fuera del método que se le pasa a `forEach`, pero se puede usar `const` para declarar `dataObj2Graph`.